# Random GET requests for POST URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, post, get

In a rails app, I see crashes frequently (airbrakes) like below

> AbstractController::ActionNotFound:The action '6826' could not be
>   found for MembersController

Investigating further, the URL is configured to receive only PUT or POST requests but instead receives GET. Doesn't seem to be action of bots or a smart user. Do browsers sometime send both GET and POST requests when a link is clicked, should it be handled in the server and redirected to corresponding pages?

Comment: May be the link is right-clicked and opened in new tab.

Comment: how do you know it's not from a bot?

Comment: Also occurs for logged in users

Comment: Can you post your routes file?

Comment: Add you routes file - I'm guessing you have some sort of "greedy" GET route that is clobbering other routes defined later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A browser will only send a `GET` request when a link is clicked - unless there is JavaScript telling it otherwise. Your app should handle `POST` and `PUT` requests for data submission, `GET` requests for data retrieval, and `DELETE` requests for data transmission. There could be several different causes of that error, it could be because you are representing a `POST` or `PUT` route using a link or your users are typing the url into the address bar.